# Netlogo Ask in-radius of a colored patch

Tags: netlogo, patch

I've seen some posts and I haven't gotten what I wanted.

I believe it's pretty simple.

I want my turtles to be in- radius 10 from a patch colored violet, However, I don't know how to ask both things at the same time.

```
create-u-pequeños 50 
[ set size 10
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = violet]
     set preferencia-uso one-of ["residencial" "agricultural" "natural"]
```

I'm missing the in-radius but I can't see it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most efficient way is to use two steps:

```
[ set size 10
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = violet]
    move-to one-of patches in-radius 10
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following could be more efficient than Steve's approach:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  
  let origin-patches (patch-set)
  
  ask one-of patches [
    set pcolor violet
    set origin-patches (patch-set origin-patches other patches in-radius 10)
    ask origin-patches [
      set pcolor violet + 2
    ]
  ]
  
  create-turtles 5 [
    set color violet - 2
    move-to one-of origin-patches
  ]
end
```

The reason why I think this could be more efficient is because here we create the `origin-patches` agentset only once (i.e. upon creation of the violet patch), instead of asking each new turtle to re-create the agentset from scratch and then moving to it.

You didn't provide a full example of your problem so in my example I made some assumptions.
Things you might want to tweak based on your actual situation:

- If you need the `origin-patches` agentset to be available in other parts of the code too (e.g. if new turtles will enter your model in other stages too) you will have to make `origin-patches` a global variable instead of a local variable to the `setup` procedure.
- I assumed that the `origin-patches` won't include the central violet patch. If that's not what you want, just remove `other`.
- If instead you don't want the central violet patch to be part of `origin-patches` (as in my example) but you will also want more than one violet patch (let's say 5), you will be good with just adjusting to `ask n-of 5 patches [set pcolor violet ...]`. However you will need to make some small changes to prevent violet patches from being included in the `origin-patches` agentset when they are close to another violet patch (let me know if this is something you need).